# loading a backbone.js collection on html page load

Tags: backbone.js

I have a question about the architecture of a backbone.js web app. Let's say you are creating a movie collection webapp. You would use a Model for a movie and a Collection for your collection of movies.

The view for the collection is basically a load of li's.

In order to make the webpages indexable by google you would allow it to work without javascript and get rendered on the server side. So that going to mydomain.com/12 would on the server side build up the html li elements for that collection.

If you then wanted to use backbone.js to modify the collection, you would need to load the data into backbone. What is the best way to do this? Two ways I can think of doing this is...

1) use jquery to iterate over the li elements reading the data into backbone - the problem with this is that the html probably only contains the movie names, and not the movie id's /director information that might be needed in the backbone model. I suppose that data could be included in the html and hidden using css.

2)throw away everything in the list and reload it from the server using ajax - which to me seems like a waste since all the data could have been sent on the first page load.

Are either of these methods good practice? If not, how should it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeremy Ashkenas, author of Backbone, recommends that you print the model data as JSON in the page, and load it as an object:

```
<script>
  Accounts.reset(<%= @accounts.to_json %>);
  Projects.reset(<%= @projects.to_json(:collaborators => true) %>);
</script>
```

See [Backbone FAQ - Loading Bootstrapped Models](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, would it be better to do something like:<script>
  var accounts = <%= @accounts.to_json %>;
</script>
and then do the reset in the foo.js file?

Comment: I couldn't say which is better or worse, it depends on how you set up your project I guess!

Comment: So to tell the whole story you have to throw out server side generated content from the DOM and render it again in Backbone (of course without additional AJAX call)?

Comment: opengrid: You don't have to. I render server side as well, so for me it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have to render server side for indexing purposes but it is too difficult to revive these elements as Backbone Views with all event handlers etc. So what works for me is when a client has JS enabled server generated contents are replaced by rendered bootstrapped JSON data that was added along the way without any additional AJAX request. Tell me if I'm wrong and there is a better way to do that?

Comment: opengrid: That is indeed the solution in the OP.

Comment: And how to achieve this when I use AMD (require.js) if I don't want to declare global variables?